# Как в Swift сохранить большое число, значение которого больше максимума типа Double?

Tags: swift

Нужно сохранить большое целое число (больше максимального значения Double) без потери точности в программе, а потом вывести его в консоль.

Например:

```
x = 135301852344706746049.0
print(String(format:"%f", x)) // 135301852344706744320.000000
```

Comment: Не используйте тип `Double`?

Comment: что использовать, если не Double? (в примере Double)

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает точность Double ?

Comment: Точности Double не хватает. В примере выше число сохранено в Double. При выводе видно, что происходит потеря точности (см. на последние значащие цифры).

Comment: А тип long double в свифте есть? Или его точность тоже недостаточна? А длинная арифметика есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть лучшее решение - использовать тип [Decimal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber)

Пример:

```
let a: Decimal? = Decimal(string: "135301852344706746049")
print(a!) // 135301852344706746049 // нет потери точности

let b: Decimal? = Decimal(string: "83621143489848422977")
print(a! + b!) // 218922995834555169026 // сложение выполнено верно
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно взять библиотеку, к примеру, эту:

https://github.com/mkrd/Swift-Big-Integer

Или поискать другие, если эта не подойдёт.